# Amazon Redshift Python UDF with Shapely: permission denied error when trying to use GEOS functions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions, shapely

I have an Amazon Redshift database set up, which contains a table with geographical markers using 3 fields: id, latitude (float), longitude (float). My goal is to write a Python UDF using the `shapely` library to:

1. Parse a multipolygon in the form of a WKT string, and
2. Return a boolean stating whether the latitude, longitude pair falls inside of this multipolygon

I used [this script](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-redshift-udfs/tree/master/bin/PipLibraryInstaller) to fetch the `shapely` library and push it to S3.

I am able to execute `CREATE LIBRARY` with the uploaded zip file, however, when I try to import `shapely.wkt` in the function, I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [500310] [XX000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: 
OSError: (13, 'Permission denied'). Please look at svl_udf_log for more information
```

Using a very simple test function that imports the library, I was able to identify some symptoms:

```
create or replace function f_test (i int) returns int stable as $$
    import shapely
    return i * 2
$$ language plpythonu;
```

Executing `SELECT f_test(2)` like this, returns a result `4`
But if I simply change `import shapely` to `import shapely.wkt`, the same error from before is thrown again.

It seems like `wkt` imports `geos`,  which will go to try and find the GEOS library on the system. I assume it's here where the permission error occurs.

In `geos.py` I see that it will look for these files in its own directory, so I tried reuploading the library zip file with those files from my local machine in the right spot, but it doesn't help.

A little out of ideas right now as to how to make this work. I found a vague reference online to using shapely in a pure python fashion, but failed to find more information on that. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: if shapely gets ANY data AT ALL from elsewhere then this CANNOT work on redshift.

Comment: Hi were you able to resolve this error? I have exact same scenario and i am trying to create a function which i was able to successfully create but when i call the function on my select stmt i am getting the above error